# CoreData, Magical Record and mogenerator

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord, mogenerator

I've just installed `mogenerator` to create the `Managed Objects` in my project.

I was working without `mogenerator` before.

I'm also using `MagicalRecord`.

I have an entity `Message` and I am trying to run the line...

```
return [Message countOfEntitiesWithPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"user == 123"]];
```

but I'm getting an `unrecognized selector` error on this line.

If I change it to...

```
return [_Message countOfEntitiesWithPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"user == 123"]];
```

It works fine. But the stupid thing is that I do this same function a couple of lines later with a different predicate and it works fine without the fix. I have tried without the predicate but get the same result.

**EDIT**

I just tried commenting this line out and putting...

```
return 0;
```

Now I get the unrecognized selector on the second use of this line. It's almost like I have to "initialise" the CoreData by calling it on `_Message` first?!?!

Any ideas?

**EDIT 2**

I'm also getting this when trying to run...

```
[Message createEntity];
```

Same unrecognised selector. This is very annoying if it's going to do this to all my Core Data stuff.

Comment: Did you include `#define MR_SHORTHAND` and `#import "CoreData+MagicalRecord.h"` in your .pch file?

Comment: @Adam Yes, I was using Magical Record fine before I used mogenerator to create the ManagedObject subclasses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know 100% that this was the answer but when I ran the project using AppCode in the iPhone simulator I saw an odd debug message that said the class Message was implemented twice.

It must have been implemented in another framework I was using or something.

When I changed the name of the core data entity back to something more unique it worked fine.

I'm surprised this compiled at all TBH.

Comment: I have the same bug. Did you find any other explanation, since then ?

Comment: No, didn't find anything since then. But I've just avoided using Message and it seems to work fine.

Comment: It seems my problem is that I don't initialize MagicalRecord before using it ! I am using the NSPersistentDocument class (an osx class). Do you ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. What I realized is Core Data does not like entities named "Message" and "Connection". Prefixing these with my custom prefix solved the issue for me.